# Is the phrase 'the holding of the meeting' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Run into this variant in an English translation, and doubt whether it is possible...

Comment: It's grammatically *possible*, but why would you want to?

Comment: What's the context?  i.e. What's the rest of the sentence?

Comment: @TrevorD 1 the rest of the sentence is like that 'The decision of the Board of Directors regarding the holding of the meeting'

Comment: Thanks. It's awkward phraseology, but it's grammatical.  It could more clearly be written as: "The decision of the Board of Directors regarding holding the meeting ..." - but why use only 3 words, when you can use 5! :-(

Comment: @TrevorD yes, agree completely with you))

Comment: You need to note that "is it grammatically correct?" type of question is off-topic here. If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, consider visiting our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically correct (because holding is a noun, and you can say other things in a similar structure like "the timing of the meeting", "the running of the meeting"), but it's not particularly elegant.